# JSP using forEach for inner classes

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a question, how to use variables of inner classes.

In myne servlet i send List of objects and there inner class.

```
    request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsersandAdress());
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
```

Send to JSP
Where i use forEach.

```
    <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${user.idUser}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.lastName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.loginName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>
        <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="${user.birthday}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.isActive}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.isAdmin}" /></td>
        <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="${user.createdTimeStamp}" /></td>
        <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="${user.lastupdateTimeStamp}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.zip}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.Country}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.City}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.District}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.Street}" /></td>

        <td><a href="UserController?action=edit&userId=<c:out value="${user.idUser}"/>">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="UserController?action=delete&userId=<c:out value="${user.idUser}"/>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

In the end Tomcat going until he get first object of inner class and talk that's not find.

Code of model:
As you can see there is 2 inner classes,Adress and Group

```
    public class User {

private int idUser;
private String
        firstName,
        lastName,
        loginName,
        password,
        email;
private Date
        birthday,
        createdTimeStamp;
private Timestamp
        lastupdateTimeStamp;
private boolean
        isActive,
        isAdmin;

public Adress adressClass;
public Group groupClass;

public User() {
    adressClass = new Adress();
    groupClass = new Group();
}

public int getIdUser() {
    return idUser;
}

public void setIdUser(int idAdress) {
    this.idUser = idAdress;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    isActive = active;
}

public boolean isAdmin() {
    return isAdmin;
}

public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
    isAdmin = admin;
}

public Date getCreatedTimeStamp() {
    return createdTimeStamp;
}

public void setCreatedTimeStamp(Date createdTimeStamp) {
    this.createdTimeStamp = createdTimeStamp;
}

public Date getLastupdateTimeStamp() {
    return lastupdateTimeStamp;
}

public void setLastupdateTimeStamp(Timestamp lastupdateTimeStamp) {
    this.lastupdateTimeStamp = lastupdateTimeStamp;
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLoginName() {
    return loginName;
}

public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
    this.loginName = loginName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [idUser=" + idUser + ", firstName=" + firstName
            +", loginName="+ loginName
            +", LastName=" + lastName + ", birthday=" + birthday + ", email="
            + email +",Adress country "+adressClass.country +"]";
}

public class Adress{
    private int
            idAdress,
            zip;
    private String
            country,
            city,
            district,
            street;

    public int getIdAdress() {
        return idAdress;
    }

    public void setIdAdress(int idAdress) {
        this.idAdress = idAdress;
    }

    public int getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(int zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}

public class Group{
    private int idGroup;
    private String role;

    public int getIdGroup() {
        return idGroup;
    }

    public void setIdGroup(int idGroup) {
        this.idGroup = idGroup;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

}

Tomcat write next:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 9
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'adressClass' not found on type model.User
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:291)
```

Any advises?
Thanks.

Comment: You have posted a question with an awful lot of methods and variables. Please, try to make a minimal example in order to ask your question --it becomes more likely for people to read, understand and answer your question if it is easier to read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks RU community stackoverflow.
Answer is - Need create getter and setter for inner classes.
And one more thing if someone will be use myne code,there is need to change in JSP page next:

```
    <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.zip}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.Country}(Country on country)" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.City(city)}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.District(district)}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.adressClass.Street(street)}" /></td>
```

Because if u don't do it, JSP page give u error and say that object not found.